# JSON Unexpected character '''

Tags: json, groovy

I get exception:

> "error_code":4001,"message":"Incorrect Request. {} [Could not read
>   JSON: Unexpected character (''' (code 39))

When execute:

```
def process = ["curl", '-k', "-X", "POST", "-H", "Content-Type: application/json", '--user', "user:pass", '-d', """\'{
               \"description\": \"string\",
               \"mode\": \"DEFAULT\",
               \"name\": \"string\",
               \"start_time\": \"2015-11-05T13:26:40.626Z\",
               \"tags\": [
               \"string\"
]
}\'""", 'https://some_url'].execute()
```

Point me my mistake please.

Comment: why do you escape `\"` in `"""` and why do you quote with `\'` at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because in a triple quoted multi-line string, you don't need to escape the `"` chars

Rather than fighting with hand crafting JSON, just use JsonBuilder:

```
def data = [
    description: "string",
    mode: "DEFAULT",
    name: "string",
    start_time: "2015-11-05T13:26:40.626Z",
    tags: ["string"]
]

String json = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(data).toString()
def process = ['curl', '-k',
               '-X', 'POST',
               '-H', 'Content-Type: application/json',
               '--user', 'user:pass',
               '-d', json,
               'https://some_url']
```

Comment: then I get this exception [Could not read JSON: Unexpected character ('d' (code 100)): was expecting double-quote to start field name\n

Comment: Added a `toString` call to the `json` variable...  Though it shouldn't be necessary